Kosit Validator Xrechnung Scheme
I'm trying to use the kosit Validator standalone cli command to get my validation report. I'm new to xsl and schematron and scenarios, so maybe I'm getting this wrong but the report only recognizes rule PEPPOL-EN16931-R008 Document MUST not contain empty elements.
Path: /rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice/rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction[1]/ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement[1]/ram:BuyerTradeParty[1]/ram:URIUniversalCommunication[1]/ram:URIID[1]
<ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
  <ram:ID>urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:xeinkauf.de:kosit:xrechnung_3.0</ram:ID>
</ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>

....
<ram:BuyerTradeParty>
    <ram:ID>15837</ram:ID>
    <ram:Name>John Doe</ram:Name>
    <ram:PostalTradeAddress>
       <ram:PostcodeCode>12345</ram:PostcodeCode>
       <ram:LineOne>exampleStreet 1</ram:LineOne>
       <ram:CityName>Munich</ram:CityName>
       <ram:CountryID>DE</ram:CountryID>
    </ram:PostalTradeAddress>
    <ram:URIUniversalCommunication>
       <ram:URIID schemeID="EM" />
    </ram:URIUniversalCommunication>
</ram:BuyerTradeParty>

Why is it not recognizing PEPPOL-EN16931-R010 rule? Because the URIID does not contain a value?
I used the standard scenario.xml including the standard resources.
Thank you in advance :-)

The rule PEPPOL-EN16931-R010 only checks, whether the element exists or not:
<rule context="ram:BuyerTradeParty">
    <assert id="PEPPOL-EN16931-R010" test="ram:URIUniversalCommunication/ram:URIID" flag="warning">Buyer electronic address MUST be provided</assert>

Thus the PEPPOL-EN1631-R10 rule is not violated. For empty elements exists the rule PEPPOL-EN16931-R008.

The problem seems to be that you did not set an email. It should look like this:
<ram:URIUniversalCommunication>
<ram:URIID schemeID="EM">noreply@something.com</ram:URIID> </ram:URIUniversalCommunication>

